# How do I check or modify the @INC in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perl, chromium

I was trying to build Chromium on Windows and met following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: webcore_bindings_sources, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 9/6/2012 11:31:11 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "..\..\..\..\..\build\Debug\obj\webcore_bindings_sources\webcore_bindings_sources.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>CustomBuild:
1>  ExceptionCodeDescription
1>  Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\bindings\scripts /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at C:\chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\dom\make_dom_exceptions.pl line 33.
1>  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\WebCore\dom\make_dom_exceptions.pl line 33.
```

It looks like my Perl path is not in the Visual Studio, so I'd like to add the path into this `@INC`, but not sure where to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that this means cygwin is not mounted properly in Visual Studio.

The solution is:

1. In Solution Explorer go to the properties of the project
2. Go to Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Build Event
3. On Command Line put:
   `$(SolutionDir)..\third_party\cygwin\setup_mount.bat`

This [thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=26) has more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try by setting the `PERL5LIB` environment variable.

There is [this nice article which explains how to **modify @INC on windows**](http://perl5maven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

Comment: Thanks. It works with one directory, however when I tried adding another path it failed, any idea how to set multiple paths for `PERL5LIB`?

Comment: try by separating them with a semicolon `;`